# Replace a failing disk in a RAID 0 array

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-0

I have a 2-disk RAID 0 array, which is reporting errors on one of the drives.  I've arranged for an identical replacement to be sent out from Dell, but I want to create an image of each partition (there are two), replace the faulty disk, then restore the image.

In summary, the two drives are in a RAID 0 array, making one logical HDD.  That HDD is then partitioned into two partitions.  I want to do whatever's necessary to swop the disk and get it back how it is now.

I'm planning on buying Acronis Trueimage or similar.  Can anyone offer any advice, or let me know if it's a Bad Idea (in which case I guess I'll just do a clean install from scratch)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure to backup everything before you attempt anything.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the new disk is identical, then it could have a different number of platters, cylinders, heads, etc. Which may throw out the RAID array.
If the RAID array is still working, backup it up first and try cloning it. If it fails, you can reset your RAID array and try a restore.

If your PC can support it, i'd suggest adding in another 2 hard drives and create a RAID 10. That way you can remove and pop in a new drive anytime. The RAID will auto-rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Acronis will do a full image no problem, its a really nice package, unfortunately it's not cheap.
Have you looked at [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)? It's freeware so could be a cheaper alternative. However depending on how your Raid is set up it may not work for you. Check out the limitations part of the web page.

Comment: Will Acronis also image the partition data?  The new HDD obviously won't have that, so it'll need to put the partitions back before putting the data in.

Comment: Yes Acronis detects partitions etc, you can do the individually or just do an exact disk image including partitions and MBR